# Vim syntax highlighting after nerd tree Plugin installation

Tags: vim, apache-pig, nerdtree

I have Pig plugin for Vim which is working fine till now. But suddenly syntax highlighting went off after I am trying to load second pig script file. It works fine only if I load a single Pig file. When I try to load another Pig file either through split or nerd tree, there is no syntax highlighting for the second Pig file. I just installed the nerd tree plugin and after  installation I saw this weird problem. Is there any conflict with the nerd tree plugin.

Comment: After some work out, I understood that its not syntax highlighting but the filetype is not getting detected for the second file .I need to set filetype=pig explicitly for the second file. I also have **filetype on**  in my .vimrc, how to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: Assuming your Pig plugin is correctly written and correctly installed, you are supposed to add `filetype plugin indent on` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I already have **filetype on**,**filetype plugin on**, **filetype indent on**,**syntax on**.Will it make any difference?

Comment: @romainl I tried it but it did't make any difference.

Comment: Could you show us your `~/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
:autocmd filetypedetect BufRead *.pig
```

a line with `setf pig` should be listed. If it's not, you haven't properly installed the filetype detection, as documented on the [plugin's page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2186). BTW, contrary to the instructions there, the script fragment would be better placed in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, not `~/.vimrc`, but it shouldn't matter.

So, place the following into `~/.vim/filetype.vim`:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pig setf pig
augroup END
```

Restart Vim, and check; the line should now be there.

Comment: When I typed the above command, I did't get any list. Also, I do not have a filetype.vim file. Can I create it manually as I did for .vim folder.

Comment: Yes, create it; I've explicitly put the contents into my answer. With that, it should work. Didn't you put something like that into your .vimrc beforehand?!

Comment: Thanks. Creating a filetype.vim and adding the above lines worked.

Comment: Yeah. Sure once I reached 15.